# serialize a non-serializable object of type Type?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, soap, xml-serialization

I have an object of type Type

```
Type typ = CreateDynamicType();
```

and the creating object of that Type

```
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(typ);
```

This instance is creating fine .Still no problem.
Now i have two methods CreateRawXML(),createSOAPXml().
Both serialize the object and return serializable string.I need a rawxml and a SOAPXML.In first case Raw XML is creating fine but when i tried to create SOAPXML it's getting error(Can not serialize object).i check the isserializable property of that object its False.As its metadata and a read only property i can't change it ..

Either i have to create a   serialize object  from that non-serializable object 
Or i need to create SOAPXML from Raw XML 
Or something else ...Please suggest ...

I am creating that Type class from CreateDynamicType() method on the fly using reflection .
I am doing it all for a WCF request
Please suggest

Comment: Would you add the contents of your CreateRawXML and createSOAPXml, or some more information on how they work (what type are you using to do the serialization, for example) if they are too complex? We can probably help you without it, but if you gave us more info we can target your question better.

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to serialize `Type` - consider if serializing full name of the type (possibly with full name of assembly it coming from to make loading of the type easier) is enough for your case.

Definitely if you try to create an object of this type in some remote process just full type name is enough (assuming the other process have access to assembly implementing the type).

Comment: I don't think he's trying to serialize Type, I think he's trying to serialize an instance of a Type. EDIT: erm, still not specific. I mean, it looks like he's getting a Type at runtime, creating an instance of it, and then trying serialize that instance.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - you right - title seem to suggest serializing `Type`, but body is not talking about it... I'll leave it as is for now - maybe OP will comment...

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  is thinking in perfect way ...I am exactly looking for the same

Comment: Does it work man ...object obj = System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices
          .GetUninitializedObject(t);